# Gatling http request not executing

Tags: http, session, exec, gatling

I'm putting an object into the session, and then in a latter step in the scenario I need to use properties of that object in an http request.

The Gatling expression language does not support accessing properties of an object, so I thought I could extract the object from the session manually and then extract the properties I needed in the http request using the following code.

```
      exec(session => {
        val project = session("item").as[Project]
        println(s"name = ${project.getName}, daysToComplete = ${project.getDaysToComplete}")
        http("Health Check")
          .get(s"/health")
          .queryParam("name", s"${project.getName}")
        session
      })
```

But structured this way the http request is not added into the chain and so does not execute.

Is there anyway to do this, short of putting the individual properties into the session. This is a simplified example. The object I'm putting into the session is much more complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered on [Gatling's official mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/gatling/c/MnBPmWyrYbM/m/BCghx_Y_AwAJ).

This cannot work, please read the documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/scenario/#exec

Gatling DSL components are immutable ActionBuilder(s) that have to be chained altogether and are only built once on startup. The result is a workflow chain of Action(s). These builders don’t do anything by themselves, they don’t trigger any side effect, they are just definitions. As a result, creating such DSL components at runtime in functions is completely meaningless. If you want conditional paths in your execution flow, use the proper DSL components (doIf, randomSwitch, etc)

```scala
exec { session =>
  if (someSessionBasedCondition(session)) {
    // just create a builder that is immediately discarded, hence doesn't do anything
    // you should be using a doIf here
    http("Get Homepage").get("http://github.com/gatling/gatling")
  }
  session
}
```

You should do something like:

```scala
foreach(components, "component") {
exec(
  http { session => 
     val component = session("component").as[ITestComponent]
      s"Upload Component ${component.getId}"
  }.post { session =>
    val component = session("component").as[ITestComponent]
    s"/component/$repoId/$assetId/${component.getId}/${component.getResourceVersionId}"
  }
  .bodyPart(RawFileBodyPart("resource", session => {
      val component = session("component").as[ITestComponent]
          component.getContent.getAbsolutePath()).contentType(component.getMediaType()).fileName(component.getContent.getName())).asMultipartForm
    }
)
}
```

Yes, this is pretty complicated. The reason it looks so over bloated is because you're trying to use a Java POJO (hidden behind an interface), instead of using Scala case classes.
If you were to use a Scala case class, you could use Gatling Expression Language (it doesn't support accessing POJOs by reflection atm) and do something like this:

```scala
foreach(components, "component") {
exec(
  http("Upload Component ${component.id}") 
  .post(s"/component/$repoId/$assetId/$${component.id}/$${component.resourceVersionId}")
  .bodyPart(
    RawFileBodyPart("resource", "${component.content.absolutePath}")
      .contentType("${component.content.mediaType}")
      .fileName("${component.content.name}")
   ).asMultipartForm
  )
}
```